# Permission denied error in tty drivers access

Tags: android, tty, android-kernel

Currently, facing an issue with this is whenever I run the app and go to SETUP in the list then it will navigate me to another screen but the issue is that is didn't able to read the drivers.
Exception:- java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/tty/drivers: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
I tried multiple ways to pass the chmod 777 permission command using the termux app as well as through system adb but didn't work.

I am using this in the rooted device. Any help will be appreciable.